# How is --ckpt-path=last supposed to work in Pytorch-Lightning?

Tags: pytorch-lightning

My understanding is that model checkpointing is enabled by default, implicitly inside the log directory. But it isn't obvious to the me that --ckpt_path=last is working as advertised. In particular when setting --trainer.logger True (implicitly tensorboard) I tried running python PL_script.py validate ... --ckpt_path=last.

It is not throwing an error, but it also gives different validation metrics than what the last log of tensorboard provides & the sha1 hash of the checkpoints produced from 'validate' and the last 'fit' run differ. I would think just evaluating a model shouldn't change the checkpoint at all...

So how exactly is this feature supposed to be used properly?